# Cassandra - Archiving a commit log

Tags: cassandra

How do i actually run the achive_commitlog command?

I've added the path to the commit log i wan to archive:

```
archive_command=/bin/ln /var/lib/cassandra/ /backup/CommitLog-3-1379341689071.log
```

But when I start/stop cassandra or use snapshot in the nodetool the log doesn't get archived. I'm a beginner in cassandra, and I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is right there in the comments:

```
# Command to execute to archive a commitlog segment                                                      
# Parameters: %path => Fully qualified path of the segment to archive                                    
#             %name => Name of the commit log.                                                           
# Example: archive_command=/bin/ln %path /backup/%name
```